# Generate a image thumbnail without stretching it with ImageMagick 6.2.8

Tags: php, imagick

Fill Area Flag ('^' flag) is support **IM v6.3.8-3**
But my client's production server has version **ImageMagick 6.2.8**
Right now in my local server i use this command to generate thumbnail and it works fine:

```
convert image.jpg -resize "280x210^" -gravity Center -crop "280x210+0+0" thumbnail.jpg
```

Since my client's production server doesn't support **'^' flag** how can i generate a thumbnail without using it? (or maybe calculating it manually in PHP or BASH)
Should i use **-extent**, does it stretch the image?
I also read **[this](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#fill)** and im not sure if ^ flag is for not letting the image stretch because thats what i want, generate a thumbnail without stretching it.

Note: *i dont have root access on the server. Im using PHP and BASH to run the commands.*

**EDIT:**
I also don't want any other background colors while resizing and croping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution
This is the **PHP** function i used:

```
function imgconvert($in,$out,$size){
  $size_arr=explode('x',$size);
  $resize=( ($size_arr[0]/$size_arr[1]) > 1.775 ? $size_arr[0].'x':'x'.$size_arr[1]);
  system("convert \"$in\" -resize $resize -gravity Center -crop \"$size+0+0\" \"$out\"");
}
```

**It seems that if width/height is larger than 1.775 i should use widthX as resize value and if else than i should use Xheight .**

Answer (score 0):

try

```
convert image.jpg -background black -resize 280 
-gravity center -crop 280x210+0+0 -extent 280x210 image.c.jpg
```